# network-manager-openvpn-gnome not able to import ovpn

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to configure OpenVPN client. When I copy the `client.conf` file to `/etc/openvpn` folder the VPN connection establishes automatically.. But I need to configure it in GUI and installed `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` and I'm getting the "Import a saved vpn configuration" menu in choose a connection type tab... The Client profile file is an autologin profile file downloaded from the VPN server.

When I try to import the `client.ovpn` I'm getting an error saying that

> "Cannot import VPN connection" The file 'client.ovpn' could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information - Error: the plugin does not support import capability.

Contents of `client.ovpn`

```
# Automatically generated OpenVPN client config file
# Generated on Sat Aug 31 16:25:23 2016 by openvpnas
# Note: this config file contains inline private keys
#       and therefore should be kept confidential!
# Note: this configuration is user-locked to the username below
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_USERNAME=testuser
# Define the profile name of this particular configuration file
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_PROFILE=testuser@vpnserver.abcde.com/AUTOLOGIN
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_AUTOLOGIN=1
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ALLOW_WEB_IMPORT=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_BASIC_CLIENT=False
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ENABLE_CONNECT=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ENABLE_XD_PROXY=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WSHOST=vpnserver.abcde.com:444
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WEB_CA_BUNDLE_START
# -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
# 
# -----END CERTIFICATE-----
# -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#
# -----END CERTIFICATE-----
# -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
# 
# -----END CERTIFICATE-----
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WEB_CA_BUNDLE_STOP
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_IS_OPENVPN_WEB_CA=0
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_ORGANIZATION=VPN to BANGALORE SERVER
setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
client
server-poll-timeout 4
nobind
remote vpnserver.abcde.com 1194 udp
remote vpnserver.abcde.com 444 tcp
dev tun
dev-type tun
ns-cert-type server
reneg-sec 604800
sndbuf 100000
rcvbuf 100000
# NOTE: LZO commands are pushed by the Access Server at connect time.
# NOTE: The below line doesn't disable LZO.
comp-lzo no
verb 3
setenv PUSH_PEER_INFO

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key (Server Agent)
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----

-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>

## -----BEGIN RSA SIGNATURE-----
## DIGEST:sha256
## 
## -----END RSA SIGNATURE-----
```

Comment: You will have issues because your file embeds the CA cert and the key (and also the `tls-auth` which I don't really know much about). Try separating those pieces in files and then apply them after importing the config without certificate and key.

Answer (score 0):

Even after installing all the plugins for network-manager I still have this error on an occasional 16.04 box.  But it is possible to configure it manually.  Here are the settings I had to set manually.

On the General page tick the box

[image]

On the VPN page enter gateway and your certificate and key files

[image]

Then click Advanced button and tick the LZO box.

[image]

I did not examine your config file in detail, so change as required to match your server settings.

Comment: I tried manually and got the error mentioned.. org.freedesktop.Notifications[2803]: ** (notify-osd:3163): WARNING **: dnd_is_screensaver_active(): Got error "Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken."

Comment: Sounds like some kind of screensaver error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting:

```
remote vpnserver.abcde.com 1194 udp
remote vpnserver.abcde.com 444 tcp
reneg-sec 604800
```

In:

```
remote vpnserver.abcde.com 
port 1194
protocol udp
remote vpnserver.abcde.com 
port 444 
protocol tcp
```

The value for `reneg-sec` could be too high as well.

Answer (score 0):

What solved all my errors like yours was the following link

https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-openvpn/

Basically, it suggests that you also install resolvconf

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```